# problem in conversion rsa private key in descriper in symbian

Tags: c++, symbian

i want to store RSA public key and private key in database

```
iRSAKeyPair = CRSAKeyPair::NewL(aModulusBits, EStandardCRT) ;

const CRSAPublicKey &iRSAPublicKey =iRSAKeyPair->PublicKey() ;

const CRSAPrivateKey &iRSAPrivateKey =iRSAKeyPair->PrivateKey();
```

but there is no datamember in CRSAPrivateKey for conv in descripter

is there any way for conversion of pointer or refenece in descripter

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See [regarding-conversion-from-reference-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909035/regarding-conversion-from-reference-to-string/911264#911264)